# async/await ftpupload damages uploaded file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to ftpupload a zipfile with async/await pattern:

```
    private async void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        await processFtp();

    }
    async Task processFtp()
    {
        string result = "";
        string ftpHost = "ftp://mysite/mysubdir";

        string ftpUser = "itsme";

        string ftpPassword = "mypw";

        string ftpfullpath = ftpHost + "/" + "OutdoorTest.zip";

        string fileToUpload = @"c:\temp\Outdoorbilder.zip";
        try
        {

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser,ftpPassword);
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000;
            request.Timeout = 1000000;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {

                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload))
                {
                    byte[] b = new byte[10 * 1024];
                    int readLength = 0;
                    int sentLength = 0;
                    while ((readLength = fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        await requestStream.WriteAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
                        int percentComplete = (int)((float)(sentLength += readLength) / (float)fs.Length * 100);
                        ftpprogress.Value =  percentComplete;
                    }
                    requestStream.Close();
                    requestStream.Flush();
                }
            }

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();


            result = response.StatusDescription;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {

            result = e.Message;
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                result = result + "Status Code : " +
                    ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
                result = result + "\nStatus Description : " +
                    ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = e.Message;
        }


        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine and I get a 226 response. But the zip file on the ftp server is arround 1000bytes biger than the original and after download to a mobile android device cannot be opend/extracted.

When I upload without async/await pattern the uploaded file has the same size on ftp server as the local original.

How/where does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with async/await.

Your problem is that you are not telling the correct size to upload. Look at these two lines:

```
while ((readLength = fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
{
    await requestStream.WriteAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
```

You need to specify that the `WriteAsyc` writes the read amount and not the amount allocated for the byte buffer. At least the last read will return less than the buffer size.

So the correct code is:

```
while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
{
    await requestStream.WriteAsync(b, 0, bytesRead);
```